# Scripting java embedd

Tags: java, scripting

Has someone embedd a simple script language in a JAVA application.

My purpose is todivide the application in 3 part

Part 1) Hardcoded in java the application read from 2 source(Db, file,scocket,..., mind) and store 2 object.

Part2) The application in conjuction with the embedded scripting language make a a decisionedit the object and at the end call an exposed function eg: if the 2 object has the same namecall the function do nthing, if the name of the second object the next step isto call the update function.

Part3) the java application do the job that has been called.

Now i'm doing this with an application that use a JAR file with a lot of interface. So if i wont to expose only the step 2 ican give the specification of interface. The idea is to copy JDBC. Anyway it's difficult for tecnichan to write and compile in pere JAVA and create a JAR. So i'm looking for a good replacement. But it has to simple but powerful as jar replacement. I'm not trying to compile evrything in a single JAR i need them well separated.

THANKS

Comment: Ok I have recived 3 suggestion:

* Groovy: a bit too complicate for simple script
* MVEL: powerful well documented
* JAVA SCRIPTING API: I like it less powerful than MVEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) for this purpose.

[Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) for example provides an implementation to load, compile, interface, and execute Groovy scripts from within your Java application.

Comment: Yes, the answer I needed. Groovy appears to be too complicated, but the link to the Java Scripting Programmer's Guide is the answer.

Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try MVEL http://mvel.codehaus.org/
MVEL is a powerful expression language for Java-based applications.
It is fast anf easy to use.
expression language = java as scripting language